# Captcha code is not working in Login Form in CakePhp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, captcha

I am using that code for captcha: https://github.com/solutudo/cakephp-captcha

That's my code in `user_controller.php` in login action:

```
    public function login() {
        if (!empty($this->data)
            && !empty($this->Auth->data['User']['username'])
            && !empty($this->Auth->data['User']['password'])) {
            // captcha code
            if ($this->RequestHandler->isPost()) {
                $this->User->setCaptcha($this->Captcha->getCode());
                $this->User->set($this->data);
                if ($this->User->validates()) {
                    // captcha code 
                    $user = $this->User->find('first', array(
                        'conditions' => array(
                            'User.email' => $this->Auth->data['User']['username'],
                            'User.password' => $this->Auth->data['User']['password']),
                        'recursive' => -1
                        ));
                    if (!empty($user) && $this->Auth->login($user)) {
                        if ($this->Auth->autoRedirect) {            
                            $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
                        }
                    } else {
                        $this->Session->setFlash($this->Auth->loginError, $this->Auth->flashElement, array(), 'auth');
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

View user.ctp

```
    <?php
    echo $this->Form->create(array('action'=>'login'));
    echo $this->Form->input('username');
    echo $this->Form->input('password');
    // captcha code
    echo $this->Html->image('captcha.jpg', array('style' => 'padding: 0.5%;'));
    echo $this->Form->input('captcha');
    // captcha code
    echo $this->Form->end('Login');
    ?>
```

Model User.php

```
    <?php
    class User extends AppModel {
        public $actsAs = array(
            'Captcha' => array(
                'field' => 'captcha',
                'error' => 'Captcha code entered invalid'
            )
        );
    }
    ?>
```

captcha code validation and captcha is not working, without entering captcha I am able to login, I have used that same code in add function with the same controller `user_controller.php`, and that time captcha code was working.

I want user to login after entering right captcha.

Comment: With debug on, do you see any errors? Do you have the component attached? A validation field on the model? How are you generating it in your view? We'll need much more information to help you out.

Comment: No i didn't found any error in debugging on mode, yes i have attached captcha component.i updated question with view and model code.

Comment: Is the captcha comparison code being run? Drop some debug statements in there. Look at the values of the submitted captcha and the one being compared against. Are their values what you expect? If not, why?  Follow the path those values take to find where the problem occurs. This is basic debugging.

Answer (score 0):

From reading the code, it looks like you have to generate the captcha before trying to validate it. I see nowhere in your code where you're generating the captcha. Perhaps you have a route pointing `/img/captcha.jpg` to a generation function (like in the docs) but I don't see that here. I also don't see anywhere where you call `CaptchaComponent::generate()` which actually saves the captcha in the session.

Make sure the following is in your `routes.php` file.

```
Router::connect('/img/captcha.jpg', array('action' => 'captcha'));
```

And place the following function in your `AppController.php` file:

```
// auto-outputs an image
public function captcha()  {
    $this->autoRender = false;
    $this->Captcha->generate();
}
```

Basically, when your image is created it actually routes to this function which creates the code and saves it in the session. The user hits submit, and your login function tries to validate. If invalid, the view is rendered and a new captcha takes its place.